# Unable to retrieve JSON body from a AsyncHttpClient Post request

Tags: android, python, json

I am trying to get make a post request in Android using AsyncHttpClient using this code:

```
    JSONObject jsonParams=new JSONObject();
    try {
         jsonParams.put("email", email);
     }
   catch (Exception e){

   }
        try {
            StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(jsonParams.toString());
            AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
           client.post(getApplicationContext(),URL,entity, "application/json",  new AsyncHttpResponseHandler(){
                 @Override
                 public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {}
                 @Override
                 public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error)  {}
    });
```

I am trying to access this data sent in the post request in my Python server. However, whenever I do request.json in my Python server, I get 'None' as response.
I also tried `request.get_json(force=True)` but getting 404 error code.
I dont really know if the data is being sent by the client APP or I am making a mistake while trying to retrieve it at the server side. Please help me with this issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
String content = new String(responseBody);
Log.e("SUCCESS_RESP",""+content);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I am trying to retrieve it at server side in Python code, getting 'None' as response over there. Just updated the question to make it more clear.